# ASP.NET MVC WebGrid helper returns whole page on partial update

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I created a web grid with ajax updating enabled like this:

```
var cerradasGrid = new WebGrid(Model.OfertasCerradas, ajaxUpdateContainerId: "ofertas-cerradas");
```

However when I check the content of the ajax request in firebug the request contains the whole page although the grid updates correctly, it takes time, I have more than one grid on the view, how can I make them return only the grid portion?

Answer (score 0):

When you say that you are seeing the entire page returned, are you referring to sorting or paging? If paging, I believe that [all data is fetched on a paged request](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=615). You can read [this article](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=618) for more information on efficient paging.

Answer (score 0):

My recent MSDN Magzine article discusses server-side paging and sorting, and partial updates via ajax. Check it out at "Get the Most out of WebGrid in ASP.NET MVC": http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/query/hh288075